# 19.04->19.10 Ethernet DHCP-Internet connection no longer working

Tags: internet, ethernet, dhcp, 19.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04. to 19.10. and unfortunately my PCI-Ethernet connection to the old Alcatel speedtouch modem does no longer provide an internet-connection via DHCP. I have set-up a live 19.04 Ubuntu USB-stick and booting the computer with this stick provides an internet connection. My windows laptop also gets this connection. I also created a live 19.10 USB-Stick and this one is working neither. The kernel version is 5.3.0.18. Network configuration is set for automatic connection and the IPv4-method is automatic (DHCP).IPv6-method also set for automatic. These settings are identical for my 19.04 and 19.10 configurations. Any idea what can have gone wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: status please...

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for taking so long. I set up a 19.04 system again and even updated the Kernel to 5.3.7 which also worked. I downloaded the 19.10. release and did a fresh install.

Comment: cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: cat /etc/network/interfaces
*-network
       Beschreibung: Ethernet interface
       Produkt: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       Hersteller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       Physische ID: 0
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:01:00.0
       Logischer Name: enp1s0
       Version: 11
       Seriennummer: 70:85:c2:4b:c3:14
       Größe: 100Mbit/s
       Kapazität:1Gbit/s
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

Comment: before all that I installed the dynamic kernel modus support and dkms status had no output 
cat /etc/network/interfaces *-network second part:
Konfiguration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=10.0.0.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       Ressourcen: irq:22 ioport:e000(Größe=256) memory:91204000-91204fff memory:91200000-91203fff

Comment: It's extremely difficult when data replies are placed into comments, instead of editing that data into your original question. I'm getting mixed messages about what works and what doesn't. 19.04 works, and 19.10 doesn't, correct? You say "I also created a live 19.10 USB-Stick and this one is working neither."... does that mean 19.10 USB works, or doesn't work? Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`? What is your MTU set to?